# email server delivers one message, but not another. no errors

Tags: email, pcap, email-server

i have sent two messages, one from the local server, one from the production environment. the message from the local server goes through, but the production message does not. both messages are identical in content. logs on server show both messages as accepted.

here are the pcap files: (local succeeds, production fails)

> http://www.mediafire.com/?sharekey=754aks7ueneoc

you may notice that the second email has a different username... i have tried it with the same username and the result does not change

any help or ideas are greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Check your spam/sanity filters. Looking at the headers of the two e-mails you have:

```
Received: from micaeked.com (micaeked.com [127.0.0.1])
.by micaeked.com (Postfix) with ESMTP id 117A390279
.for <19162188541@tmomail.net>; Sun,  8 Aug 2010 15:33:10 -0700 (PDT)
Received: (from micaeked@localhost)
.by micaeked.com (8.14.4/8.14.4/Submit) id o78MX9YA026943
.for 19162188541@tmomail.net; Sun, 8 Aug 2010 15:33:09 -0700
From: micaeked@micaeked.com
Message-Id: <201008082233.o78MX9YA026943@micaeked.com>
Date: Sun, 08 Aug 2010 15:33:09 -0700
To: 19162188541@tmomail.net
Subject: EURGBP
User-Agent: Heirloom mailx 12.4 7/29/08
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
```

vs

```
Received: from macbook-PC (adsl-75-45-9-58.dsl.scrm01.sbcglobal.net [75.45.9.58])
.by micaeked.com (Postfix) with ESMTPA id 1DAF390279
.for <19162188541@tmomail.net>; Sun,  8 Aug 2010 15:41:28 -0700 (PDT)
From: "Max Matush" <maxmatush@micaeked.com>
To: "Mica Eked" <19162188541@tmomail.net>
Subject: USDCHF
Content-Type: text/plain;
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
```

The missing required headers (Message-ID, Date) is the most likely reason your e-mail is dropped by the server. What does it say in the server logs?

Comment: i am sending these emails to a server i do not own, so cannot check their logs. my server reports no errors. i also have no control over the client, so cannot change the message there. is there any way to force these headers on the server if they do not exist?

Comment: Deliver them to a local smtp daemon that creates a proper e-mail and then forwards it to the server?

Comment: ok, i was able to add the missing headers using the "always_add_missing_headers" directive in postfix. i verified that the headers are added using tcpdump, but it still does not work. any ideas?